# Measure of Gain of scores

Tags: repeated-measures

I would like to perform in Rstudio a measure of Gain of scores on a dataset of repeated measures "pretest" "posttest", and print the relative plot. 
Could you give a guideline of functions and code to use? I read different procedures online and I got a bit confused.

Thank you!